# How do I use the rehype-inline-svg plugin with Astro?

Tags: svg, astrojs

I've got an Astro project using markdown content collections for blog posts. In these posts I have svg images referenced as so:

`![image-1](/assets/images/image-1.svg)`

This shows the SVG inside of an `<img>` tag but I want to inline the SVG in these scenarios. This is where the [rehype-inline-svg](https://github.com/JS-DevTools/rehype-inline-svg) plugin is supposed to help me. But when I add the plugin into my Astro config, I get an error `ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/assets/images/image-1.svg'`

I have tried several paths to reference this image, but none work. I figure at the very least, the path should stay the same. I am not sure what else to do to get this to work. My Astro config is as follows:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';
import inlineSVG from '@jsdevtools/rehype-inline-svg';

export default defineConfig({
  markdown: {
    rehypePlugins: [inlineSVG]
  },
});
```

My original goal was to display Excalidraw SVGs with the font. Fonts need to be embedded if contained within an `<img>` tag so I am trying this inline approach. I would be happy to know if you have a good automated technique for achieving this too.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, is `/assets/images/image-1.svg` in your `public/` directory? Looking at `rehype-inline-svg`’s code it looks like it tries to resolve SVG paths relative to the root of the project, so you might need to include `public/` in your Markdown somewhat unusually:

```
![image-1](public/assets/images/image-1.svg)
```

Comment: Yes, the SVG is in `public/assets/images`. I tried adding `public/` but the error suggests that it is trying to resolve from the directory of the markdown file. Prefixing with `/public/` has the same issue failing to resolve. Even a full path from the root on my machine to the file fails.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the previous answer `rehype-inline-svg` plugin looks for a path relative to the root of the project. However, for some reason plugin's working directory is `src/pages`.

So this should work for your case:

```
![image-1](../../public/assets/images/image-1.svg)
```

Comment: I gave this a try, but it appears that content collections don't support relative directories. "Relative image paths are not supported in the content/ directory."